# read element attribute in OnClick event

Tags: jquery

I have A html element and would like to read data attribute in OnClick event

```
<a id="downloadFile" class="btn btn-success" href="javascript:;" data="MyData">Download file</a>
```

If I use code below this refer to href atribute and not to A element. How to refer to A element and read data value?

```
 $('#downloadFile').click(function() {            
  alert(this.attr('data')); //I get error that 'href' do not has 'data' attribute, this code refers to href attribute and not to A element
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the context of an event handler, `this` refers to the DOM element, not the jQuery object. Use `$(this)` to get a jQuery object so that you can use the `attr` function:

```
$('#downloadFile').click(function() {            
  alert($(this).attr('data'));
});
```

Another option is to use [`this.getAttribute("data")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getAttribute).

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/h2KFR/)**.

Comment: I didn't know about the element.getAttribute() function. Kudos!

Answer (score 1):

You can have custom data attribute and separate it with `-`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/tjJV6/)**

```
<a id="downloadFile" class="btn btn-success" href="javascript:;" data-yourhref="MyData">Download file</a>   

     $('#downloadFile').click(function() {            
        alert($(this).data('yourhref')); //Get error that href do not has data atribute, this refered to href atribute and not to A element
    });​
```

Comment: Finally one answer that mentions the true usage of the `data`.

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to js object using this but using jquery syntax.

Try:

```
$(this).attr('href')
```

Answer (score 0):

Only change THIS for the propper selector for Jquery

```
$('#downloadFile').click(function() {            
          alert($('#downloadFile').attr('data')); //Get error that href do not has data atribute, this refered to href atribute and not to A element
        });
```